# Comparing timestamps in MySQL

Tags: mysql

The timestamp in my database is in the following format:

```
2011-02-26T13:00:00-05:00
```

But getting the current timestamp via MySQL with:

```
SELECT current_timestamp();
```

Gives me something formatted like...

```
2011-02-26 13:05:00
```

My end goal is to go through all entries (each 2 days) and delete those older than 2 days so how would I compare the entries with the `2011-02-26T13:00:00-05:00` timestamp to the current timestamp?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT DATE(`yourtimestamp`) FROM thetablename WHERE DATE(`yourtimestam`) < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you store your date (in your preferred format) in a character-based column (`VARCHAR` et al).

Don't. It's a) bad style, b) you run into issues such as this. Instead, use the standard timestamp type, and if you need that specific ISO format when querying from the database, then format it accordingly.

If you store your times in the native format, then comparisons between different dates become trivial `<` and `>` comparisons.

Comment: That makes sense but I'm a junior programmer working on a small piece of a much larger project.

Comment: I agree with andri, it would have been better to start off with the proper data type.